# Eclipse RCP Job cancel() method always returns false

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I develop Eclipse RCP plugin and I want to folow advice that Eclipse RCP shows on application shutdown:

```
Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown
```

My problem is, that I retrieve false when I call job.cancel(). When I call job.cancel in loop that checks if result is finally true, then this loop is endless. 
Is there any other way to force job to be brutally interrupted? I want to be sure, that my plugin closed all the jobs that it created.

Comment: That could help you http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html

Answer (score 3):

If the job is actually running `Job.cancel` sets a flag to tell the job it has been cancelled and then returns `false` to indicate the job may not have stopped yet.

The `Job` needs to override `cancelling` if it needs to respond to a cancel request, the default does nothing!